# Executar comando externo em Java com sintaxe

Tags: java, eclipse

Olá, eu estou usando um arquivo do DOS para descompactar arquivos .zip, é o próprio UNZIP.EXE (executável do DOS) estou montando o código da seguinte forma:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("e:\\unzip.exe teste.zip" ));
```

Não funciona de jeito nenhum, ele da um erro dizendo que o arquivo ZIP não foi encontrado, já testei dessa forma, e também não deu certo:

```
ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder();
p.command("e:\\unzip.exe", "e:\\teste.zip");
p.start();
```

Também não deu certo, o que estou fazendo de errado ? Basicamente preciso executar o comando unzip.exe com o nome do arquivo ZIP na sequência, apenas isso.

Agradeço qualquer ajuda! Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Dei uma olhada no [`doc`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) e você teria que passar uma lista de `String` com os parâmetros e não dessa forma que você fez, experimenta:

```
ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder(new String[]{"e:\\unzip.exe", "e:\\teste.zip"});
p.start();
```

Comment: não deu certo, ele executou mais simplesmente não faz nada e nem da erro.

Comment: @user7605 se vc der um `getInputStream()` ele não mostra nada?

Comment: como posso fazer isso ? se puder me passar o comando, comecei em mexer em java a pouco tempo, eu agradeço!

Comment: Após o `p.start();` você pode pegar o inputStream com o `p.getInputStream()`, pra ler ele pode utilizar [essa função aqui](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-inputstream-to-string-in-java/).

Comment: @user7605 dê uma olhada /\

Comment: estou testando...

Comment: @Maiicon Carraro, ele não deixa eu usar o p.getInputStream();, apenas o p.getclass();

Comment: realmente não deu certo aqui!